# Receive form data on email

Tags: php, forms

How may I get data of this form to be received in an email?

```
<form class="pa">
    <fieldset>
        <label>Name <em>*</em></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="">
        <label>Email <em>*</em></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="">
        <label>Age <em>*</em></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="">
        <label>Phone <em>*</em></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="">
        <label>Zip Code <em>*</em></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="">
        <a class="submit pa" href="#"><img src="wp-content/themes/child/img/submit.png"</a>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a server-side script to accept the form data, and send an email with it. You can do this PHP and several other languages. Judging by your sample code you have WordPress, so you might look into the [ContactForm plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/).

Comment: Definitely make sure that you are including some sort of client verification in order to avoid possible exploits of your server side email script.

Answer (score 0):

wrap your input's with something like

```
<form class="pa" action="yourscript.php" method="post">
    .
    .
    <label for="name">Name <em>*</em></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="" id="name" name="name">
    .
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <!-- remove the a tag because that won't submit your form data or use type="image" -->
    <input type="image" src="wp-content/themes/child/img/submit.png" />
</form>
```

then use `$_POST['name']` to retrieve the value
you have to add `name=''` to each inputs to have them sent to your script eg `<input type="text" id="name" name="name">` and they have to be different otherwise they might get overridden.
also your labels will need the `for=` to be useable which uses the `id` of the `input` eg `<label for="name">Name <em>*</em></label>`